# How can I stream DivX video in Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10 x64?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, divx, streaming, totem

DivX used to work for me, even if not perfectly, on older releases of Ubuntu up until very recently.  I used to be able to play, pause and buffer the stream (but was unable to rewind any portion of the video) with Totem codec and plugins.  With installation of Maverick, Totem seems to have stopped working as well.  When that ceased working, I removed all Totem files from my computer.  I tried using `gnome-mplayer` and `gecko-mediaplayer` for Firefox but to no avail.

- I've tried reinstalling `totem`, `totem-plugins`, `totem-common` and `totem-mozilla`
- I ran `dpkg-query --list totem-mozilla` and got the desired output `ii  totem-mozilla  2.32.0-0ubuntu Totem Mozilla plugin`.
- I also checked `about:plugins` and it is enabled there

I'm not sure if this problem is either:

- due to missing packages that need to be installed or conflicting packages that are already on the machine, or
- due to the fact that I'm running an x64 version of Maverick with flash64 and java6 (seeing as how both are still in experimental phase).

I would like to keep both flash64 and java6 because they don't seem to be causing problems with anything else other than streaming DivX.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit please? It's very hard to tell what you're asking. Improving your spelling, grammar, and [formatting](http://superuser.com/editing-help) would also help make things more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for getting back so late but i was finally able to solve this problem for me...

With Ubuntu you need to completely remove Firefox first from your system before reinsatlling plugins to purge any conflicting files left over from previous installations.

1) Removing Firefox and all previously installed plugins through synaptic manager is the easiest way to do so

2) Reinstall Firefox, gecko-mediaplayer and all associated dependencies.

And that is it, divx playback should be working for you.  I'm still unable to to seek the track at all, even for the portions of the video already buffered.  Not sure, but i think that this is a glitch in divx playback in linux; if anyone has the solution to this little glitch your input would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems unlikely due to a missing driver or plugin since I was in the same position and was able to play .vls (streamings) directly in Firefox.

Installed VLC and it works fine.